# Line breaks in PHP email from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code that works - apart from not splitting into separate lines for each result.

```
<?php>

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lending");
 //fetch the data from the database 
$entries = 'Entries: '; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$entries .= $row['bookname'] . ', "/r"';
}
{
?>

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
//$entries = wordwrap($entries, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
mail('me@example.com', 'My Subject', $entries);
?>
```

When I run this I get an email looking like this:

Entries: Test ASIN, "\r"Test ASIN, "\r"Test ASIN, "\r"Test ASIN, "\r"Test ASIN, "\r"The Expectant Father: Facts, Tips, and Advice for Dads-to-Be, "\r"Animal Farm, "\r"Hornet flight, "\r"

Where should I put the "/r" to have it parsed properly?  Or should it be "/n/r"?

thanks!

Alex

Comment: use `\r` and `\n` rather than `/n` and `/r`

Comment: Entries: Test ASIN, "\r"Test ASIN, "\r"Test ASIN, "\r"Test ASIN, "\r"Test ASIN, "\r"The Expectant Father: Facts, Tips, and Advice for Dads-to-Be, "\r"Animal Farm, "\r"Hornet flight, "\r"

feel like the "\r" is in the wrong place in the code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code has /r instead of \r.